# Convert PDF to .txt file with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: pdf, google-cloud-storage

I have this code for Python on a local file system.

What is the equivalent Python object API for `os.getcwd()`, `os.listdir`?

I want this code to work using files from GCS?

In order to use GCS folders, I include this code

```phython
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.bucket('my-bucket')
pdfDir = bucket.get_blob('uploads/pdf/')
txtDir = bucket.get_blob('uploads/txt/')

from cStringIO import StringIO
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
import os
import sys, getopt

#converts pdf, returns its text content as a string
def convert(fname, pages=None):
if not pages:
    pagenums = set()
else:
    pagenums = set(pages)

output = StringIO()
manager = PDFResourceManager()
converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)

infile = file(fname, 'rb')
for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
    interpreter.process_page(page)
infile.close()
converter.close()
text = output.getvalue()
output.close
return text 

#converts all pdfs in directory pdfDir, saves all resulting txt files to 
txtdir
def PDF2txt(pdfDir, txtDir):
if pdfDir == "": pdfDir = os.getcwd() + "\\" #if no pdfDir passed in 
for pdf in os.listdir(pdfDir): #iterate through pdfs in pdf directory
    fileExtension = pdf.split(".")[-1]
    if fileExtension == "pdf":
        pdfFilename = pdfDir + pdf 
        text = convert(pdfFilename) #get string of text content of pdf
        textFilename = txtDir + pdf + ".txt"
        textFile = open(textFilename, "w") #make text file
        textFile.write(text) #write text to text file

pdfDir = "C:/pdftotxt/pdfs/"
txtDir = "C:/pdftotxt/txt/"
PDF2txt(pdfDir, txtDir)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you want is to list objects in a bucket and objects in particular folders inside a bucket. For doing that you can use directly the Python Client Libraries that Google Cloud Storage provide. Use `bucket.list_blobs()` for listing the whole bucket and `bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix, delimiter=delimiter)` for listing a particular folder or object.

A more detailed documentation can be found here [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) and the Git repository containing the whole libraries here [[2]](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/storage).

Comment: Right, i want to list and read all the pdf files in pdfDir and process as txt to txtDir.

Comment: Instead of  **pdf in os.listdir(pdfDir):** I have used **pdf in bucket.list_blobs(pdfDir):** but for **if pdfDir == "": pdfDir = os.getcwd() + "\\"** i have search the documention but couldn't find anything for os.getcwd() As GCS  is a flat namespace and doesn't have folders ad subdirectories. Can i use something like  **pdfDir = bucket.get_blob('uploads/pdf/')**

Comment: you can use `pdfDir = bucket.get_blob(prefix='uploads/pdf/')`.